# How does block comparator work in Obj C?

Tags: objective-c, sorting, objective-c-blocks

This is not a how do I do this post. Instead, I want to understand how it works and hopefully others can learn too.

For this example, let's say I have an NSMutableArray with NSDecimalNumber objects in them. Let's say the objects inside, in no particular order, are `[-464.50, +457.20, 0, -1000]`. Prior to comparing them, I apply the absolute value to them.

In my code, I use the `sortUsingComparator` method and give it a block. I started testing the different conditions and here is the result as they are presented in a UITableView:

```
return [person1Amount compare:person2Amount];
==> 0, 457.20, -464.50, -1000
```

If,

```
return [person2Amount compare:person1Amount];
==> -1000, -464.50, +457.42, 0
```

How does the `compare:` method actually works. The `NSDecimalNumber` doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) does not really explain it to me. This part especially confuses me:

> Return Value NSOrderedAscending if the value of decimalNumber is
>   greater than the receiver; NSOrderedSame if they’re equal; and
>   NSOrderedDescending if the value of decimalNumber is less than the
>   receiver.

Does that mean that the order of objects inside the array determines how it is sorted? For example, if `person1.number < person2.number`, it will sort array in ascending order? Why does my code `[person2Amount compare:person1Amount]` yield the right results?

It looks like `person2Amount is < person1Amount` and so it sorts it descending but if `person2Amount is > person1Amount`, then it will sort is in ascending?

My understanding does not seem right.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are comparing absolute values, lets ignore the signs. Your numbers are 464.50, 457.20, 0, and 1000. Ascending order means the numbers get bigger, so the order would be 0, 457.20, 464.50, 1000. Descending order means they get smaller, so the order is 1000, 464.50, 457.20, 0.

When you use a comparator, the array sorts in ascending order according to the comparator. It sends pairs of values to the comparator. If the comparator returns that they are in ascending order, it places the first one first. If it returns that they are in descending order, it places the second one first.

The NSNumber `compare:` method works basically like this (of course you can't use `>` and `<` on NSNumbers, but it's the idea):

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSNumber *)number2 {
    if(self < number2) return NSOrderedAscending;
    if(self > number2) return NSOrderedDescending;
    return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

Therefore, if your comparator calls `[number1 compare:number2]`, the result will be ascending if the numbers are ascending (number 1 is smaller), which means they will stay in that order and be ascending in the array. If the comparator switches them, `[number2 compare:number1]`, the result will be ascending if the numbers are descending (number 2 is smaller), so they will get switched and be descending in the array.

Comment: I still don't understand. Let's use examples. For the array above [464.50, 457.20, 0, 1000] and we want to sort ascending so [number1 compare:number2]. The first pair is [464.50 compare:457.20]. Looking at your compare method, self is number1 so in the statement (self > number2), since 464.50 is greater than 457.20, it will return true and return NSOrderedDescending. But [number1 compare:number2] returns the array in ascending order. That is what I don't get. Maybe there is a play on words but it is confusing to me.

Comment: @Yko The comparison returns descending, and the array always uses ascending order based on the result of the comparator, so when you return descending it tells the array to switch their order. Try writing down each step of the sort. First compare the first pair, and if the result is descending, switch them. Keep doing pairs until they stop switching.

Comment: What does "array always uses ascending order based on the result of the comparator" mean? So, the first pair returns NSOrderedDescending since number2 > number1. But then based on that comparator, the array returns it in ascending order, so the array will rearrange it as [number1 number2]. If I set is as [person2 compare:person1], it will return NSOrderedAscending. What does "array uses ascending order" mean? Since it is already ascending to leave it alone? So, it will be [person2 person1] which is right. Can you confirm the conclusions I have here?

Comment: If what I said above is true, then the key part is 'array always uses ascending order based on the result of the comparator' which is something I did not know.

Comment: Right. What I mean by "ascending order based on the result of the comparator" is that if the comparator returns ascending, they stay in that order, and if it returns descending, they get switched. The array does not care about the actual order, just the result of the comparator. If your comparator randomly returned ascending or descending, the result would be randomly sorted.

Comment: Cool. Oh so that's what that means. Then, it all makes sense. I thought from the ascending and descending it orders it in that way and that is confusing. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

It seems you've answered your own question.

```
return [person1Amount compare:person2Amount];
```

vs.

```
return [person2Amount compare:person1Amount];
```

Consider the above two statements;   the `compare:` method returns `NSOrderedAscending` or `NSOrderedDescending` depending on which of the two objects are greater than the other.

If you were to do:

```
return [@1 compare:@2];
```

vs.

```
return [@2 compare:@1];
```

Then the you'll received `NSOrderedAscending` and `NSOrderedDescending` for what should be obvious reasons.

Thus, if you implement your own `compare:` method and you switch the two objects used to compare (as in the @1 vs. @2 case above), you'll effectively reverse the sort order of the array.

Comment: It is not obvious to me. Let's use examples: For the array above [464.50, 457.20, 0, 1000] and we want to sort ascending so [number1 compare:number2]. The first pair is [464.50 compare:457.20]. Looking at the compare method, self is number1 so in the statement (self > number2), since 464.50 is greater than 457.20, it will return true and return NSOrderedDescending. But [number1 compare:number2] returns the array in ascending order. That is what I don't get. Maybe there is a play on words but it is confusing to me.